# How to create an auto-direction text field for a multi-line text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need an auto-direction textField for multiline text in flutter but I have no idea how to create it
I need something like this photo.

[image]

Comment: are you using two different column for this? if so you can wrap the Column with Directionality widget.

Comment: I don't think this is a standard way because deleting the word and adding textField after newLine is a complicated task @YeasinSheikh